# SQLAlchemy table reflection with Sybase

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sybase

When I try to reflect all tables in my Sybase DB

```
metadata = MetaData()
metadata.reflect(bind=engine)
```

SQLAlchemy runs the following query:

```
SELECT o.name AS name
FROM sysobjects o JOIN sysusers u ON o.uid = u.uid
WHERE u.name = @schema_name
AND o.type = 'U'
```

I then try to print the contents of metadata.tables, and this yields nothing.

I've tried creating an individual `Table` object and using the `autoload=True` option, but this yields a TableDoesNotExist error.

```
accounts = Table('Accounts', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
```

I looked into this query and it seems the @schema_name is becoming my username, and none of the tables which come from "sysobjects" appear to have a "name" attribute set to my username. They are all set to "dbo", which means the Database Owner, and thus the query returns nothing, and nothing is ever reflected. Is there any way to force SQLAlchemy to use something different as schema_name?

I've found two questions regarding table reflection using the Sybase dialect. Both were asked 6 years ago and seem to indicate that table reflection with Sybase was unsupported. However, it seems that SQLAlchemy tries to run a genuine sybase reflection query as above, so I don't think this is the case now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by setting the `schema` parameter on the `MetaData` object. I had to set it to `dbo`. You can also specify this in the `reflect` function.